# Find Table object in query

Tags: sqlalchemy

Using sqlalchemy 0.7.2

Is there a way to find the table class from the query object?  For example:

```
q = session.query(Customers)
```

how can I find `Customers` in `q`?  Possible? Not Possible?

Answer (score 11):

Yes.  You need `column_descriptions`.

It's a long road to the table, though.  `sqlalchemy.orm.Query.column_descriptions` returns a *`list` of `dict`s*, describing each query entity as it was given to `query`.  in your example, there's only one entity, so you need the first item from that list.  And since you're interested in the type of the query entity, rather than its' structure, you want the `"type"` key from that list:

```
q_entity = q.column_descriptions[0]['type']
assert q_entity == Customer
```

Accessing the table for the mapped class requires snooping around in the mapper subsystem.  for that, you should use `manager_of_class`.  The table is accessible from the manager through the `mapper.mapped_table` attribute:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm.attribute import manager_of_class
q_table = manager_of_class(q_entity).mapper.mapped_table
```

Resist the urge to skip strait to the `mapper` through `Customer.__mapper__`, or even `Customer.__table__`; That's specific to `sqlalchemy.ext.declarative`, and won't work with classes that are mapped by other means.